# Origin point coming out of nowhere

Tags: modeling

I have this object that shows an extra origin point.
[image]

If I isolate selection, it disappears completely.
[image]

If I get back from isolate selection, it's again there.

The long stick is a completely isolated object, just a box, that I never parented to anything.
It is suspect also that isolating the "couple" of objects, still only shows one object, the right one.

If I Shift + Select another object, the extra origin point disappears.
[image]

Also, up to now pressing Alt + A to deselect all, always leaves visible the origin of the last object selected. Is this normal?

This troubles me a bit, for fear that the scene is going to be corrupted sooner or later.
The impression I have, is that Blender introduced an extra origin somewhere, linked to nothing, after I imported, reorganized and deleted several empty origin points coming from GLTF objects (that come with so many useless extra nodes...).

Edit: grabbing only moves the object: the extra origin point stays there.
[image]

Nothing selected, floating origin point:
[image]

I am really scared now.

Comment: It can be an empty object which used to be linked one and the link was broken at some point. Anyway, it should be possible to find this object via viewport and Outliner (try to select that point in viewport, then press Numpad dot in Outliner to move to that object, then select it via Outliner). Once it's selected, see its name if it helps to learn its meaning, enter Edit mode and look for geometry or delete it

Comment: switch to wireframe view and you should be able to see what is what.